# Devise: setup user default templates upon user confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, confirmation

What I want: Using Devise for user sign up, login etc... When a user signs up and is confirmed, I'd like to create a bunch of user default templates for that user.

What I've tried: 
I've attempted to override Confirmations#show so that show.html.erb would be the view and #setup_user_defaults() is called upon successful confirmation. 
    class ConfirmationsController Devise::ConfirmationsController

```
    def show
      render('show')
      setup_user_defaults()
      super
    end
```

I keep getting an error that says I can only have 1 redirect or render in an action. The reason why having this view is important to me is because #setup_user_defaults() takes a little too long for comfort that a user might hit refresh or something screwing up the process

My thoughts: I am a newbie and haven't learnt about background jobs yet. So, my question is: Is this a background job? Or how can I get #show to have a view that says "Your account is being set up. This may take a few minutes." Without using AJAX (I'm not at that point yet).

Or any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the error because you're calling `render`, and then you're calling `super` which also has a render or redirect inside of it.  You can't call either render or redirect more than once in a method (unless it's encapsulated into a conditional if statement).

Also, you don't need empty parenthesis in order to call a method like you do in javascript.

Now.  Any large or slow running task is ideal for backgrounding.  And even though you're new, If you're using rails 4.2, background jobs are so simple these days!

I would use delayed_job, its easy and flexible. So these are the steps:

**1. Add delayed_job and daemons to your gemfile & run bundle install**

```
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'daemons'
```

**2. Make sure the method to set up your templates is in the User model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  def set_default_templates
    ### this is where all your setup code will go, remember that you're inside the object itself, so if you need to reference data stored already you'll use self, e.g. self.name or self.confirmed_at
  end
  handle_asynchronously :set_default_templates
end
```

***NOTE*** *Make sure you add the handle_asyncronously line with your method name, this tells the model that this method should ALWAYS be called using ActiveJob (this is the wrapper that lets you use any background service you want but your code doesn't change in the mode)*

**3. Now it's time to call the method, 2 choices: Call the method from the controller, or call the method in an `after_create` callback**

I recommend doing this in the `after_create`, its just a little cleaner.  So in your model, use the same code as above, but add this line under the devise declaration:

```
after_create :set_default_tempaltes
```

If you would prefer to do it in the controller you *can* but remember with devise it must be done inside the registrations controller, so when a new user signs up, it happens in the create method:

```
def create
  super
  if resource.save
    resource.set_default_templates
  end
end
```

***NOTE*** *Know that until you fully understand what these devise methods are doing, I don't recommend overriding them, and think you're safer using the after_create callback*

**4. Now generate your delayed job**

```
rails generate delayed_job:active_record
```

**5. Launch the background process from a command line**

```
bin/delayed_job start
```

Also if you're using unicorn and foreman for your application server there are other steps you'll need to take, but those are outlined in tutorials and here on StackOverflow, so just search or create a new question if you get stuck

Comment: I've gone through your very clear tutorial and I've also looked at the documentation but I am confused. I thought the whole point of 'handle_asynchronously' was that I didn't have to quit the rails server and then run 'rake jobs:work' then quit that and run rails s again? I don't understand how delayed_job works. Could you point me to a tutorial on delayed_jobs or explain this process of using delayed_job? Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

You cannot [double render](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#avoiding-double-render-errors) the same page from the same action. But you can split them into two actions. First make sure that the email confirmation is successful and if it is, redirect them to another action (must override [devise's Confirmations#show](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb) without calling `super`):

```
def show
  self.resource = resource_class.confirm_by_token(params[:confirmation_token])
  yield resource if block_given?

  if resource.errors.empty?
    flash[:notice] = "Your account is being set up. This may take a few minutes. 
                      Please wait to be redirected."
    redirect_to setup_defaults_path
  else
    respond_with_navigational(resource.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity){ render :new }
  end
end
```

In the second action, the flash message set above should be shown while user waits for `setup_user_defaults` to finish. Once that's successful, finally redirect them to their profile or whatever you want.

```
def setup_defaults
  if setup_user_defaults()
    redirect_to after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
  end
end
```

Ideally, you would create a background Job, but to achieve what you were trying to do, the above should do it. I hope that helps!

Also here is a great tutorial on background processing with with sidekiq: https://ryanboland.com/blog/writing-your-first-background-worker/